# Read number from stdin and save as integer directly, using read() function

Tags: c, linux, pointers, stdin

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
    int num;
    int read_bytes = read(0,&num,sizeof(int));

    printf("read %d bytes :[%d]\n",read_bytes,num);
}
```

when I execute this code, it returns just random integer like 724109877

Why this happend?
also glad to hear if someone tells me right way to read number from stdin and save as integer

Comment: You'll probably be getting textual input from `stdin` but `read` is typically used for binary input. Try using `int items = scanf("%d", &num);` When you wrote "random integer like 724109877" was that the *actual* value you read, or some random value off your fingertips?

Comment: What are you giving your program for input?

Comment: some random value, but it seems like has some relation such as   
input 1 for 7329123 and input 2 for 7329124

Comment: That 'random' value is the ASCII (or compatible) character codes for `5 NL ) +` on a little-endian system, or `+ ) NL 5` on a big-endian system. I would add that for most C implementations _by default_ stdin reads textual data from the _human user_, but usually you can redirect stdin to read from a file or program which usually could be either textual or 'binary' (raw) depending on a large number of factors you have completely ignored.

Comment: When i run the program, it runs like scanf.

Comment: Please give the *actual* input and output, not "some random number". You are telling `read` to input 4 bytes: are you entering 4 bytes? You will get more information if you initialise `int num = 0xAAAAAAAA;` and output the value in hex too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by reading a line and convert it to a number later:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    size_t  nb_bytes, buffer_size = 32;
    char    *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * (buffer_size + 1));
    int     number;

    buffer[buffer_size] = '\0';
    nb_bytes = getline(&buffer, &buffer_size, stdin);
    number = atoi(buffer);

    printf("read %zu bytes :[%d]\n", nb_bytes, number);

    free(buffer);
    return (0);
}
```

Note that `nb_bytes` will include the newline character, you can substract 1 to get the length of your number.

**2nd solution**

You can also simply use scanf, and then if you need to get the number's length, you can compute it easily. Here's an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

size_t get_number_length(int n)
{
    size_t length = n < 0 ? 1 : 0;

    if (n == 0)
        return (1);
    while (n != 0)
    {
        n /= 10;
        length++;
    }
    return (length);
}

int main()
{
    int number;

    scanf("%d", &number);
    size_t number_length = get_number_length(number);

    printf("read %zu bytes :[%d]\n", number_length, number);

    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char num[100];
    char *p;
    int read_bytes = read(0,num, 5*sizeof(long)); // increase size according to your input
    long n = strtol(num,&p,10);

    printf("read %d bytes :[%ld]\n",read_bytes,n);
}
```

Data is read in the form of text from console.  You need to convert it to integer as above.

Comment: This code don't work if you provide a number > 9999. The numbers of bytes that `read` takes actually is the number of characters if will read from stdin, so if you provide a number that has more characters than `sizeof(int)` (often 4), it will trucate this number

Comment: It's the same with `sizeof(long)`, it's not relevant as sizeof(long) is often 8 and an int can be 11 characters long (INT_MIN)

Comment: Agree. We have to increase its size, based on our requirement. If you think, you need higher value, increase the size. Multiply by some factor .